# Informal English sentence correction

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, formality

> What you gotta hose for?

1. Is is correct, can I use this sentence in informal english?
2. How can I say this sentence formally?

Comment: What is the sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: It's like you are on a trip and suddenly someone pulls out a hose outta their bag and you ask them "what you gotta hose for?"

Comment: *Gotta* is always incorrect in Standard Written English.

Comment: Nowadays people are always whipping out hoses, no one is safe, I say it's gotta stop.

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing it incorrectly. It's not "gotta", it's "got a". "you got" is a nonstandard way of saying "do you have", so the whole sentence is informal for

> What do you have a hose for?

"gotta" is normally used as a contraction of "have got to", as in

> I gotta go to the store.

Comment: Isn't "gotta" short for  ***have** got to* ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, although "I have" is usually reduced to a contraction "I've". So "I gotta" is short for "I've got to"

Comment: Which, interestingly, is equivalent to "I have to" -- "got" is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

As *informal* English it is perfectly fine/horrendous depending.

More formally "Why have you got a hose?" And with some urgency the contraction of "gotta" is just fine. If not the detailed situation of the fire fighter there may be more fundamental philosophical questions at large.